# Immediately starting a new activity from an activity

Tags: android

When I was originally learning about Android a few months ago I swear I read something about a way to immediately launch an activity when starting a task.  I am curious about this now because I need to display an intro screen on launch but I don't want the intro screen to be the root activity.  Does anyone know if there is something like this and if not what is the best way to handle an intro screen?

I tried googling for a few hours to find it but can't for the life of me.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6):

Here are a couple of options, using `IntroScreen` and `RootActivity` as placeholders for your two `Activity` classes:

1. Have the `IntroScreen` be the one in the manifest that has the `LAUNCHER` `<intent-filter>`, so it is what the user opens up. When it is time to switch to the `RootActivity`, `IntroScreen` uses `startActivity()` to start `RootActivity` and then calls `finish()` to remove itself from the stack.
2. Have the `RootActivity` be the one in the manifest that has the `LAUNCHER` `<intent-filter>`, so it is what the user opens up. In `onCreate()` of the `RootActivity`, call `startActivity()` for the `IntroScreen`. When the user BACK buttons out of the `IntroScreen`, the `RootActivity` will appear.

Personally, I prefer option #1.

Comment: #1 works pretty well, thanks. Depends on what you want the BACK button to do I guess.

Comment: Just a note on #1: Whatever label you give the initial activity will be what is used on the Applications menu. So you'd want to make these activity labels the same as your main activity.